# Setting of Images in Blackberry

Tags: image, blackberry, button, background

May I know how to set background images to a Button in Blackberry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following links:

- [User Defined Buttons - Create a Custom Button From an Image](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_custom_button_1676236_11.jsp)
- [Tutorial: Creating a custom button](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_custom_button_1676236_11.jsp)
- [Blackberry Custom Button Field](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-custom-button-field/)

You can get your customized button by extending **ButtonField** or **Field**. In case of ButtonField you have to override default **paint(...)**, **paintBackground(...)**, **drawFocus(...)**, **applyTheme(...)** etc.

*paint(...) - can draw image or other geometric figures instead of text*

*paintBackground(...) - define how should your button's background look*

*drawFocus(...) - define how the button looks when it got focus*

*applyTheme(...) - do nothing if you want to remove default styling*

If you extend **Field**, you will get more option for customization.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the article, [ButtonField with Image as a BackGround.](http://pradeeppankaj.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/buttonfield-with-image-as-a-background/) It will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code here which explains to create [custom-image-buttonfield-in-blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/02/custom-image-buttonfield-in-blackberry.html)